# Categorizing product data model

Tags: magento, e-commerce, datamodel, categorization

I'm about to rebuild an e commerce website with a mid sized database of about 40,000 product.
One of the main reasons we are putting the old system to retire is the categorization mechanism.

We are looking for something that will allow us to place an item under multiple categories, or even better having no fixed category at all and we can classify products by putting descriptive labels on them and the front user can search for the products by using these labels. (I don't even sure that this can be done from a programming point of view).

It will be helpful to know what this model is called, whether it was implemented before? and even better if you can refer me to ready solutions.

Comment: Labels/tags are tricky and error prone as they tend to be free form and manually entered. Magento (as well as other ecommerce platforms) has some of this functionality: Flexible categories and product attributes which can be used for faceted navigation.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Any recommendation for a tool that would enable me to make magento categories more flexible ?